# 'Watch' command doesn't work in bash script called by Ganymed library in Java

Tags: java, bash, scripting, ganymede

I've a script. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
watch -n300 java -jar myapp.jar > out.log &
mkdir aaa
echo "App accesa"
```

When I call this myscript.sh from my app in Java with the Ganymed library it doesn't execute the watch statement but the 'aaa' folder has been created.
My statement in java is

```
Session sess = conn.openSession();
String command = "cd /root/;./myscript.sh";            
System.out.println(command);
sess.execCommand(command);
```

I can't understand the problem why if I run the myscript.sh script from console it works fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Technically, you have a shell script, not a bash script. A bash script would begin with `#!/bin/bash`. How do you run `myscript.sh` from the command line? What if you remove the shebang? Try `sh myscript.sh` vs `bash myscript.sh`. Do you get the same result?

Comment: From command line I run this script by this command: ./myscript.sh I already tried with sh myscript.sh, but the result is the same. By console it's all ok, but with ganymed the watch statement command doesn't work

Comment: What if you remove the shebang and then try with `bash myscript.sh` and `sh myscript.sh`?

Comment: Always the same. By console it's all ok, but from my app that statement doesn't work

Comment: But if I remove this 'watch -n300' it works also by my app but only one time